# Nonlinear Regression with significant squared term but insignificant linear term

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model

I need assistance to interpret my regression output from R. The initial output shows that age squared is significant whilst age is not as shown below:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.408e+00  8.765e-01   6.170 1.11e-07 ***
GEN         -1.007e-01  6.642e-02  -1.516  0.13563    
AGE2         1.455e-04  4.314e-05   3.372  0.00143 ** 
PEMP         7.723e-03  5.462e-04  14.140  < 2e-16 ***
TEMP         7.387e-03  1.580e-03   4.675 2.19e-05 ***
PROD         8.583e-01  5.989e-02  14.332  < 2e-16 ***
CoAGE        4.262e-03  1.603e-03   2.659  0.01043 *  
REG         -1.554e-01  5.887e-02  -2.639  0.01099 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

But I read an article by Coad, Segarra and Teruel (2016) indicating that if quadratic/interactive term is significant (for me that's `AGE2`), then one has to include the linear term (in my case `AGE`). So I have done that (by adding `AGE` to the model) but now both terms are insignificant in the final output as shown below:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.829e+00  1.442e+00   3.349 0.001530 ** 
AGE          7.488e-03  5.578e-02   0.134 0.893743    
AGE2         4.545e-05  6.046e-04   0.075 0.940366    
PEMP         7.986e-03  5.636e-04  14.169  < 2e-16 ***
TEMP         6.542e-03  1.714e-03   3.817 0.000367 ***
PROD         8.833e-01  5.929e-02  14.897  < 2e-16 ***
CoAGE        3.670e-03  1.623e-03   2.262 0.027989 *  
REG         -1.336e-01  6.334e-02  -2.110 0.039780 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Should I report the final results as my findings even though both `AGE` and `AGE2` are not statistically significant?

If so how do I justify it? Or should I completely ignore `AGE2`, but how do I justify that since it's significant before `AGE` is added?

I would appreciate assistance. Please refer me to any scientific articles so that I can cite to justify whatever final decision I should make on this.

Comment: Coad, Segarra and Teruel (2016): full reference please. You ask for citations but don't give full details in your own!

Comment: Here, as in many other examples, the R output is insufficient to explain what you are doing. What is the response variable? What is your sample size?  Why are you fitting a quadratic in age but (it seems) leaving all other predictors as they come? On the face of it the dominant effects are through `PEMP` and `PROD`, which may leave little scope to determine a separate age effect.

Comment: Why do you call this nonlinear regression? What is the function call you used in R?

Comment: What @NickCox means about this perhaps being linear regression is that $\hat{y}_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \beta_2x_i^2$ is a linear regression. "Linear" regression means linearity in the parameters.

Comment: In general a predictor and its square can't have separate effects because they must be highly correlated. It's possible that a quadratic makes sense even if conventional significance levels that imply only one -- or even none -- of the two predictors is acceptable. The decision is as much scientific as statistical.

Comment: Did you center age before squaring it?

Comment: Standard practice is to perform an F test to compare the model without any age variables to the model with *both* age variables.  This is often known as an "analysis of variance."

Comment: @NickCox here is the link to the article I cited >> https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0048733315001687

Comment: @NickCox I am trying to assess the impact of owner's age and its long term effect  (using age squared) on firm sales. Since i included a quadratic term i am not sure if i can still call that linear regression. I used this function call in R>> lm(LogSALES~AGE+AGE2+PEMP+TEMP+PROD+
                        CoAGE+REG,data = qdata)

Comment: That is linear, as already explained by @Dave.

Comment: @Dave my research supervisor argued that the moment we include higher terms in the model then it ceases to be linear. Would you be able to help me with literature to the contrary, I will really appreciate if you can

Comment: @NickCox would you be able to help me with some literature i can cite to prove my case, i will really appreciate if you have something. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, no:  I cannot advise easily on references for two reasons. First, I am not an economist and do not work with business or finance data. Second, the request is backward: you want references to support whatever decisions you will make. So, in effect, you want briefings for all possible decisions. Sounds like politics to me, not statistics or science.

Comment: Page #3 of Agresti's "Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models" says, "The explanatory variables themselves can be nonlinear functions of the underlying variables, such as interaction terms...or a quadratic term". I also like MathematicalMonk's discussion of how to use (nonlinear) basis functions to produce a feature space: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVviNyIR-fI&list=PLD0F06AA0D2E8FFBA&index=53&t=0s. Be courteous when you bring this up with your professor, but it's just plain wrong to call  $\hat{y} = a + bx + cx^2$ a nonlinear regression.

Comment: That said, here's a sketch of arguments for completely polarised attitudes. First, cut all variables that have trivial effects. The argument is one of parsimony, simplicity or avoiding overfitting, all keywords that will lead to enormous literatures. Second, include all variables which you can justify in terms of theory, which in this field appears to mean often that some previous author made a case why this could be a good predictor.Then you can make a case that you tested a bundle of hypotheses and also that your model includes predictors that may capture minor but not trivial effects.

Comment: Thanks much for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

First, as the comment thread reveals, this is not nonlinear regression.

Second, I asked in the comments whether you centered age before squaring it. This is usually recommended.

Third, I think you are over-relying on significance tests. Why did you look at a age-squared in the first place? Do you suspect, on theoretical grounds, that the relationship between the dependent variable and age would be curved? It is entirely permissible to include nonsignificant terms in your model (although some PHBs will argue).

(PHB = Pointy Haired Boss, from Dilbert. It could be a manager, a committee, an editor ...)

Fourth, when a relationship is complicated, I often find it useful to look at a spline relation. It's also helpful to look at a scatterplot of the DV and age.

Comment: @ Peter Flom Thanks, I didn't centre my age, maybe it's something I should do and run the model again. Yea, based on theoretical grounds I suspect a curve linear relationship between sales and the age of the business owner, in fact from my descriptive stats, it seems old business owners (above 60) are more successful than young business owners, hence my inclusion of age sqrd to empirically assess if owner's age has positive effect on performance as he/she gets older